# Prevent Conversion of same Drawing file to svf File again when Forge Viewer is called

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

We have integrated AutoDesk Forge Viewer. We are sending a request to the Forge API's for conversion (using Model derivative API). After closing the Viewer, If we need to show the same file again, Currently we are posting the dwg file again for conversion to view it.

Instead is there a way so save the svf file in my local system so that I need not call the Forge web service twice for the same file.

According to the pricing, for every simple conversion job, its going to cost [0.2 credits](https://forge.autodesk.com/pricing).

Please suggest how I can avoid this same conversion second and n number of times.

Thank you,

Shiva Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the DWG file has changed, you do not need to upload the DWG file again and/or POST a translation again. If you do this, you will effectively consume 0.2cc. Instead, just reference the URN you had received after upload/translation when starting the viewer. The 'bubble' or SVF persists on the backend depending of the [storage policy](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/) you chose. For example, if you create a transient bucket, the file and bubble will persists for 24h, temporary for 1 month, and persistent forever.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please shed more light in the way of saving the svf file in my local system with help of urn?

Comment: Well, this is a different question - Visit this [website](https://extract.autodesk.io) and its [github repo](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io) for the source code. While this is possible, I would recommend that you choose another approach documented [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a reference to how to iterate through the bucket and see the files which are present in the bucket.

We can login in the below live demo using the forge credentials.

[Live Demo](https://derivatives.autodesk.io/)

[Source Code](https://github.com/adamenagy/oss.manager-nodejs)

Thanks.